# Using ""formalized" for a solution

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, synonyms

`This is a formalized version of the solution`. Is this sentence correct ? What are alternative
words one could use apart from `formalized`. The context is :
I solve a question but in a rough way. After that I write it formally to submit it to the prof
In this context apart from `formalized` what other words one can use

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest, in the context, you say it is the *finished*, *final* or *finalised* version of the solution.

You should use the definite article, ie "*the* final version", as there may have been several drafts but there is only one final version.

Comment: Just to provide more info. The context I am using in is - eg. I solve a math problem roughly and then I make it neat and clear step by step for submission

Comment: @Amitwadhwa okay, on reviewing the context I can see a number of my suggestions were not quite suitable. I've narrowed it down to 3.